# Laravel-4 and phpmyadmin installation in fortrabbit

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, laravel-4, fortrabbit

I would like to know how to install phpmyadmin along with Laravel-4 project in fortrabbit..The problem is that if the phpmyadmin folder is in the laravel's project folder an exception not found is caused..If I have it outside Laravel's folder I heve a problem with the root path...Any ideas..?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good idea to put a 3rd party application in the /public/ folder of you laravel app. Instead you can put your /pma/ folder at root level and point a new subdomain (like pma.yourproject.com) to that folder.